# wget and run/remove bash script in one line

Tags: bash, shell, wget

```
wget http://sitehere.com/install.sh -v -O install.sh; rm -rf install.sh
```

That runs the script after download right and then removes it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you might need to actually execute it:

```
wget http://sitehere.com/install.sh -v -O install.sh; ./install.sh; rm -rf install.sh
```

Also, if you want a little more robustness, you can use `&&` to separate commands, which will only attempt to execute the next command if the previous one succeeds:

```
wget http://sitehere.com/install.sh -v -O install.sh && ./install.sh; rm -rf install.sh
```

Comment: Thanks. I had do also chmod u+x as well but I got it. You also do not need -O

Answer (score 62):

I like to pipe it into sh. No need to create and remove file locally.

`wget http://sitehere.com/install.sh -O - | sh`

Comment: could you please explain why the second `-` is required to be piped to bash?

Comment: This one actually works compared to other answers, it runs the install after download.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the best way to do it:

```
wget -Nnv http://sitehere.com/install.sh && bash install.sh; rm -f install.sh
```

Breakdown:

- `-N` or `--timestamping` will only download the file if it is newer on the server
- `-nv` or `--no-verbose` minimizes output, or `-q` / `--quiet` for no "`wget`" output at all
- `&&` will only execute the second command if the first succeeds
- use `bash` (or `sh`) to execute the script assuming it is a script (or shell script); no need to `chmod +x`
- `rm -f` (or `--force`) the file regardless of what happens (even if it's not there)
- It's not necessary to use the `-O` option with `wget` in this scenario. It is redundant unless you would like to use a different temporary file name than `install.sh`

Comment: _"This is redundant unless"_ ...what?

Comment: Yes I am aware this is 8 years old.  It's amazing to me that in all that time nobody pointed out the -N here is irrelevant since the command they are using is deleting the local copy each time.

Answer (score 0):

You are downloading in the first statement and removing in the last statement.
You need to add a line to excute the file by adding :

```
./install.sh
```